# Adding delay to jquery drop down menu

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add delay to a simple drop down menu. With the following code I get a delay but wrong kind. When I move my mouse over the menu really fast, it delays it but still opens it after the 300ms. The right behavior would be to open the menu when the mouse has hovered 300ms on it, same when leaving it.

```
$('#menu-item-1226:not(.parent-pageid-1225 #menu-item-1226)').hover(function(){
    var menu = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(menu).find('ul').slideToggle(100);
    }, 300);
});
```

Do I have to `stop` it somehow or what is the right approach here? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for, however using the Jquery Plugin HoverIntent will work as well, and maybe even better.

without hover intent:

```
$(function() {
        var timer;
    $('#Header li').hover(function(){
                if(timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = null
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                           $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(100);
                }, 500)
    },
    // mouse out
    });
```

});

with [hover intent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

```
$("#Header li").hoverIntent({
    sensitivity: 7, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
    interval: 50,   // number = milliseconds of polling interval
    over: function () {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(220);
    },  // function = onMouseOver callback (required)
    timeout: 0,   // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut function call
    out: function () {
        $('ul', this).hide();
    }    // function = onMouseOut callback (required)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But somehow I can't get this to work... Is this a working piece of code or do I need to adjust it somehow?

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not yet tested it. However this is the way to do it. I adjusted it a bit to your needs, that's probably where I went wrong.

Comment: I'm working on it, i'll post you the correct syntax as soon as I have it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
:)

Answer (score 0):

This Post contains sample fiddle code and its working fine.

[JQuery dropdown menu using slideup and slidedown on hover is jumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713513/jquery-dropdown-menu-using-slideup-and-slidedown-on-hover-is-jumpy)

Answer (score -1):

just use `delay()`

```
$(menu).find('ul').delay(300).slideToggle(100);
```

You say delay in ms, after that just your effect.

Comment: This will have the same effect as mentioned above, when you move over your mouse very fast it still opens the menu.

Comment: you posted it at the wrong solution.
my post was before his ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
$(menu).find('ul').delay(300).slideToggle(100);
```

Comment: This will still cause the menu to display, just with a delay of 300ms.