# Infinite height on jquery dropdown (slideUp and slideDown)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, height, slidedown, infinite

Basically I created a dropdown menu with jquery by using the slideUp and slideDown functions. Everything worked good until I figured that if I continue hovering the mouse through the list, the height of the sub button won't stop. And we can see that by the border-left expanding. Any way to avoid this?

I've created a fiddle so that you guys can know what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/WGm8q/

Anyway here's the code:

**JS**

```
$('.button').hover(
    function () {
        $('.sub', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.sub', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    width: 850px;
}
.button .main {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button .sub {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.button .sub p {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="main">Menu 1</div>
        <div class="sub">                    
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>                 
            <p>Submenu 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Your Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt2Au/)

Change this:

```
.button .sub {
display: none;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Into:

```
.button .sub {
display: none;
margin-left: 10px;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: It worked. But this way I don't have the lines extended. No way to go around it?

Comment: Padding is your problem here, workaround to fix that  is to add a fixed height to your menu (but that has its own issues) , or maybe to "wrap" your sub menu in another div that has no height but has border and padding (didn't test it...)

Comment: Another maybe best solution is to add padding to your LAST or FIRST menu item... Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/THWhZ/

Comment: Yep, I went to lunch and thought about the exact same thing :D Thanks Dejo

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a gem of a fiddle that will clear up your problem too I believe:

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GgdEM/1/

The problem with this one was a jumpy menu, which I think may be the cause of your border issue (event firing going all screwey).

The key is to have a timeout that will clear itself when hovered again.

[JQuery dropdown menu using slideup and slidedown on hover is jumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713513/jquery-dropdown-menu-using-slideup-and-slidedown-on-hover-is-jumpy)

He does this through the data attribute of each menu item so each item is dealt with independently.

Take a look:

```
$(function () {    
  $('#nav li').hover(function () {
     clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
     $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
  }, function () {
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    }, this), 200));
  });
});
```

His fiddle doesn't seem to have any border issues either so perhaps have a look at his markup and css.

Comment: It's similar. Though in my case, apparently I just had to remove the padding. His case is useful too - even when he goes away with the mouse and returns a while back, the dropdown restores :)